# Why is tag and name equality required for struct/union compatibility?

Tags: c, struct, c99

C99 standard has the following language in section 6.2.7.1:

> two structure, union, or enumerated types declared in separate translation units are compatible if their tags and members satisfy the following requirements: **If one is declared with a tag, the other shall be declared with the same tag.** If both are complete types, then the following additional requirements apply: there shall be a one-to-one correspondence between their members such that each pair of corresponding members are declared with compatible types, **and such that if one member of a corresponding pair is declared with a name, the other member is declared with the same name**. For two structures, corresponding members shall be declared in the same order. For two structures or unions, corresponding bit-fields shall have the same widths. For two enumerations, corresponding members shall have the same values. (emphasis added)

In particular, this rule makes these two `struct`s with identical layout incompatible, because their tags and member names do not match:

```
struct x_type {
    int x;
};

struct y_type { // << Different tag
    int y;      // << Different member name
};
```

It is easy to understand why member types and their declaration order must be the same. However, it is not clear why tags and member names need to match as well, even though they do not influence binary layout of `struct`?

Comment: For compiled code I also see no reason, but maybe for an interpreter?

Comment: Perhaps for more strict type checking? If you want compare two objects, make them of exact same type..

Comment: Surely for the usual reason, it makes the compiler writer's job easier.  Very early versions of C did not yet have tags and structure members were added to the one-and-only symbol table.  When it got added, hardware was still very modest.

Comment: Structure assignment would defy intuition with the proposed relaxed definition of *compatible type*.

Comment: @HansPassant: "Very early versions of C did not yet have tags" Can you provide a reference? AFAIK, `typedef` was added later, so how would different `struct`s have been differentiated?

Comment: @Olaf: While structs did have tags, but member names were not associated with them.  A declaration like `struct foo {int w,x,y,z;}` would, on the PDP-11 (a 16-bit machine), effectively set members w, x, y, and z to int@0, int@2, int@4, and int@6, and if `q` was *any* structure type, q.y would treat the bytes at offsets 2 and 3 as an `int`.

Comment: See also [Why do structure type declarations in different translation units need to have identical tags to be compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75806524/15168)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text you quote isn't talking about layout-compatible types, it's talking about types that are **the same type**. That rule is how C defines whether two definitions of a type are valid re-definitions of the same type.

In your example you're damn right that `x_type` and `y_type` aren't compatible, because they certainly don't describe the same type! If they were compatible it would mean that calling `void foo(struct x_type*)` with an argument of type `struct y_type*` would be valid, which is certainly not the intention.

The text you quote and the following paragraph are the C equivalent of the C++ ODR, and requiring the tags and member names to be the same is similar to this wording from [basic.def.odr]:

> Given such an entity named `D` defined in more than one translation unit, then
>
> — each definition of `D` shall consist of the same sequence of tokens; and
>   — in each definition of `D`, corresponding names, looked up according to 3.4, shall refer to an entity defined within the definition of `D`, or shall refer to the same entity, after overload resolution (13.3) and after matching of partial template specialization (14.8.3), [...]

Comment: Presence of overloads make C++ case very different, and rather easy to understand. C standard, however, talks about compatibility, not sameness, of the types: "two structure, union, or enumerated types declared in separate translation units **are compatible** if ..." If I define `void foo(struct x_type)` in one translation unit, then declare `extern foo(struct y_type)` in another translation unit, and make a call, it's undefined behavior, yet I cannot think of a technical reason why this wouldn't work with any C compiler.

Comment: Indeed, but the 6.2.7.1 rule isn't describing what technically works because the right bytes happen to be at the right offsets, it's describing how the type system decides if two types are the same or not, which is an important part of the type system. Without that it might as well not bother having a type system :)

Comment: In other words, you are saying that this is done for philosophical, rather than technical, reasons? I guess that's fair, although it is uncharacteristic of C language designers, whose goal, it seems, has been to combinine the speed of assembly language with the expressive power of assembly language.

Comment: Yes. C stopped being a high level assembly language long ago.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Some compilers like gcc will assume that an access made via pointer of type `struct x_type*` cannot possibly affect any members of a `struct y_type`, even if the member names and types match perfectly.  It will even make such assumptions even if a union declaration is visible which contains both structure types.  I do not see how such behavior can be termed compliant in the latter case, but the authors of gcc seem to think it is.

Comment: Read 6.5 in the C standard. It says you have to do accesses through the correct type, or through a union that includes the type. It's not enough to just have such a union defined somewhere in the program (and if you think about it, whether it's visible or not would be a dumb rule, things would break when you do simple refactoring and move things to other files). This isn't some GCC-specific interpretation, it's what the standard says.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Prior to C89, nearly every C implementation made it possible to have structures treat pointers to many structure types interchangeably for purposes of using the common initial portions thereof.  This ability has been present since 1974, and is absolutely essential for many kinds of programming.  Basing aliasing analysis upon the visibility of a union type declaration would allow existing code to be made conformant by adding `union` declarations for every combination of actual and re-punned type that the program relies upon.  That may not be the best way to handle that...

Comment: ...but any language which omits such a vital feature of the C language invented by Dennis Ritchie is at best a pale subset of that language.

Comment: I'm sure WG14 would love to hear your thoughts on the matter.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I don't know the best way to contact anyone who would be directly involved.  I think the biggest problem with any kind of "C Standard", however, is that there because exist useful programs and useful implementations which are not compatible and cannot reasonably be made compatible, any single language definition which tries to promise that all programs will run on all compilers will either be incapable of expressing semantics that are needed for many purposes, or unimplementable on many platforms where a reduced version of the language would be useful.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: What would really help resolve a *lot* of issues, including aliasing, would be to recognize the concept of "selectively-conforming" programs and "selectively-compliant" implementations.  A program would be selectively conforming if it used some additional standard macros to specifies features and guarantees it requires beyond the default features and guarantees, would run correctly without UB on any platform which supports the specified features, and would be rejected by any compliant platform that didn't support them.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: A fully-compliant implementation would be one which guarantees to run *all* strictly-conforming programs; a selectively-compliant one would be required to capable of correctly running at least one program and would be allowed to reject any or all others, but must correctly run any selectively-conforming program that it does not reject.