# Why do structure type declarations in different translation units need to have identical tags to be compatible?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

[Section 6.2.7 Compatible type and composite type](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.2.7) of the C99 specification states that

> [...] Moreover, two structure, union, or enumerated types declared in separate translation units are compatible if their tags and members satisfy the following requirements: If one is declared with a tag, the other shall be declared with the same tag. [...]

The [C99 rationale](https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) mentions as a "quiet change in C99", without explanation, that

> Structures or union type declarations in different translation units now must have identical tags to be compatible.

What is the reason for this strict type of naming rule for tags of structures for them to be compatible?

As I understand this rule, the following structs would not be compatible if their declarations were in different translation units

```
struct coord {int x; int y;};
```

and

```
struct point {int x; int y;};
```

Comment: I think it is to to make their usage less error-prone rather than some technical reason.

Comment: Imagine the confusion if you have `struct coord {int x; int y;}` in one TU, and `struct coord {int y; int x;}` in another.

Comment: @Barmar Your example does not apply to my question. I have included an example.

Comment: See [C99 Rationale](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf), sec 6.2.7, page 45

Comment: @cafce25 oops that seems to be a very similar question indeed. I will study the answers

Comment: @tstanisl I think that is what I mentioned in my post, but I do not see an explanation in 6.2.7, it just mentions the change.

Answer (score 4):

The technical specifications of “compatible” in the C standard essentially mean two types are compatible if they can be completed to be the same type. For example, `int [3]` and `int []` are compatible, because the latter can be completed to be `int [3]`.

Note that this is the common English meaning of “completed,” not quite what the C standard means by “complete,” because the C standard specifies “complete” or “incomplete” for object types, but this notion of compatibility applies to function types too: `int (int, float)` is compatible with `int ()`.

This notion of compatibility is used by the standard to describe the language and support compiler behavior where two types might be the same type but the information is not completely available. For example, when assigning one pointer to another, we might not have complete information about the types, but, if they could be the same type, we want to accept the assignment. On the other hand, if we know the types are not the same (even after allowing for permissible differences in qualifiers and such), we want to issue a diagnostic about the assignment.

For structure types, `struct { int a, b; }`, `struct foo { int a, b; }`, and `struct bar { int a, b; }` are all different types and no two of them can be completed to be the same type, so they are not compatible.

Comment: Eric, I closed this as a duplicate but your answer and the other are both *very* nice. This *may* be a case for reversing the closed-target direction, or even requesting that a moderator merge the two questions. Feel free to ping me with your thoughts, or discuss in the [SOCVR chat-room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56124252#56124252).

Comment: @AdrianMole: The original makes a mistake of introducing “layout compatibility” for “compatibility,” and that is not addressed in my answer. I think a way to proceed might be to draft a new question along the lines of “What is compatibility of types, does it have anything to do with memory layout, and why do structures need to match in tags and member names?” (Or maybe just tags. I am not sure why the standard says member names have to match, and that might be a separate subject.)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have two translation units, `file1.c` and `file2.c`.  There's only an issue if you need to pass data of the structure type from functions in one TU to functions in the other TU.

Since you need prototypes for the functions in both TUs (C99 or later demands that, even if compilers have only taken to enforcing it more recently), what name are you going to use for the parameter types in the function declarations in the header(s) that will be used by both TUs?

It has to be a common name unless you throw away the major benefit of prototypes and place near duplicate declarations for the functions in the individual TUs, rather than placing a common declaration in a header.  This loses the cross-checking ability provided by headers — which is a serious problem.

Taken in isolation, the older rule sort of worked, provided you never made a mistake.  The new rule helps ensure that the code really does work by requiring consistent naming.  Also, the older rule existed before there were function prototypes.  Function return types other than `int` had to be declared, but there was no specification for the types of the parameters to the functions.

Of course, C++ takes it a stage further with its type-safe linkage rules.  There, the type names must be consistent, or the code won't link.